# How to change python script that it continue with looping if file not exist

Tags: python, dataframe, os.walk

With my script, I loop over multiple subdirectories and create a dataframe of 3 files that are in the subdirectories. I want to write the output of each subdirectory to each subdirectory, but my code gives an error: "df1 not defined" at the line with

```
dfmerge1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['genome', 'contig'], how='outer')
```

This is probably due to the fact that not all files exist in a subdirectory and the script stops. I want that the script continues with the next subdirectory if one subdir not contain all three files. How can I do that?

My code is

```
import os
import pandas as pd

print('Start merging contig files')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    filepath = os.path.join(root, 'genes.faa.genespercontig.csv')
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f1:
            df1 = pd.read_csv(f1, header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names = ["contig", "genes"])
            df1['genome'] = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(filepath))

    filepath = os.path.join(root, 'hmmer.analyze.txt.results.txt')
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f2:
            df2 = pd.read_csv(f2, header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names = ["contig", "SCM"])
            df2['genome'] = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(filepath))

    filepath = os.path.join(root, 'genes.fna.output_blastplasmiddb.out.count_plasmiddbhit.out')
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f3:
            df3 = pd.read_csv(f3, header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names = ["contig", "plasmid_genes"])
            df3['genome'] = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(filepath))

    #merge dataframes
    dfmerge1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['genome', 'contig'], how='outer')
    df_end = pd.merge(dfmerge1, df3, on=['genome', 'contig'], how='outer')

    #set NaN in columns to 0
    nan_cols = df_end.columns[df_end.isnull().any(axis=0)]
    for col in nan_cols:
        df_end[col] = df_end[col].fillna(0).astype(int)

    df_end.to_csv(os.path.join(root, 'outputgenesdf.csv'))
```

Comment: Your assumption may be wrong. If the first `if` statement doesn't execute, `df1` is never defined, but you still try to merge `df1` and `df2`. Check that the files exist.

Comment: `os.path.isfile(filepath)`  seems to return False for the first file. Have you checked it?

Comment: Can I change the loop, that it skips the subdirectories that not contain all files, and continue with the subdirectories that do contain the files, instead of stopping the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correctly checking for the presence of `filepath` but you are not handling the case where the file does not exist. So if the file is not there, then either `df1` will be a leftover value from the previous loop iteration, or  undefined if this is the first time through the loop.

```
if os.path.isfile(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f1:
        df1 = pd.read_csv(f1, header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names = ["contig", "genes"])
        df1['genome'] = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(filepath))
else:
    continue
```